# What is the correct Device Definition for Google Glass (for a simulator in Eclipse or Android studio)?

Tags: google-glass

Yes I will test on the actual device (when it arrives) but would be nice to know now:

How to setup a device definition so I can run an emulator that is something like glass.

**Critical are:**

Size: What size does glass "report" itself as: Small, Normal, Large,    XLarge

Screen Ratio: notlong or Long?

Density bucket: xxhdpi? or what?

Other: does setting it up for DPad input help at all or come close to the nav on Glass? Other tips?

**Note**: Yes I know about the mirror API playground, but I'm developing APKs not mirror-api.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

DisplayMetrics gives this output on Glass Explorer edition:

DisplayMetrics{density=1.5, width=640, height=360, scaledDensity=1.5, xdpi=180.62222, ydpi=169.33333}

So it does indeed look like hdpi.

Also the screen size is small:

```
....
else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {     
               Log.d(TAG,"SMALL screen");
           }
```

And it is "notlong"

Answer (score 13):

I created an AVD with the following specs:

Screen Size: 3"
Resolution: 640x360
RAM: 682 MB
Size: Small
Screen Ratio: notlong
Density: hdpi

and its a pretty good representation of my Glass, though its not perfect. I don't know what the exact screen size should be but with that resolution and density, looking at XML layouts in the Graphical Layout Preview look accurate.

Comment: Are you able to debug the demo GDK apps on an AVD created this way, or is it just for layout testing?

Comment: We weren't creating a GDK app actually, it was for a regular Android application. Yes, the original intent was for layout previewing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

As for Enterprise Edition 2, according to [Tech Specs](https://www.google.com/glass/tech-specs/), I configured new hardware profile for virtual device as following:

**Hardware profile:**
[image]
**System image:**
[image]