# Resource target for native Google Glass?

Tags: android, google-glass

What folder should be used for layouts and resources for Google Glass?  I know the dimensions are 640x360, which puts it in the 'normal' size.  What is the screen density?  ldpi? mdpi?

This would be helpful to know for native apps using same apk across devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is small-hdpi, so if you are running non-mirror api apps on it, it will pull from that folder (drawable-small-hdpi, layout-small-hdpi, etc). I have confirmed this through actual teesting with Glass

See this stackoverflow question for more info: [What is the correct Device Definition for Google Glass (for a simulator in Eclipse or Android studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490150/what-is-the-correct-device-definition-for-google-glass-for-a-simulator-in-eclip)